# Implicit namespace and service reference

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've got a service reference of type *ServiceReference* in the namespace *MyNamespace*, containing some data classes' definitions. That leads to the following syntax in my CSHTML file.

```
@foreach(MyNamespace.ServiceReference.MyDataType blopp in ViewBag.Blopps) ...
```

This is less than convenient and I'd like to be able to go like this, instead.

```
@foreach(MyDataType blopp in ViewBag.Blopps) ...
```

In a CS file, I'd apply *using* for this but what's recommended approach for the CSHTML file?

EDIT

Of course, **besides** `@using MyNamespace.ServiceReference;` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
@using MyNamespace.ServiceReference
```

EDIT:

Since in your edited question you specified, besides `@using`, you can add the references in `web.config` file but they will be available for all the views.

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
      <!-- Add following with others -->
      <add namespace="MyNamespace.ServiceReference" />
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: Right, my bad. Your answer **is** correct. It's my question that's wrongly worded. Please see the edit.   :)

Comment: Yey! :) (and additional more than 8 characters)